# Python Selenium: Find child of sibling in a table and click it

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table and I want to click every checkbox on a row containing the word *empty*.
The checkbox is a child of a sibling in the HTML-code (I hope I'm using the correct terms). [Screenshot of HTML-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiGQl.png).

I've managed to make a list of of all elements containing *empty* with this:

```
empty = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'empty')]")
```

How can I use this list to find the checkbox in the same row?
I'm using Selenium with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try one of these this xpath :

```
//tr[td[contains(text(),'empty')]]//input

//td[contains(text(),'empty')]/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second suggestion worked.